# Launch Authenticator process from controller in Symfony 5+

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony5.4

I'm trying to write a SSO authentication bundle for Symfony 5.4+

When I try to access pages with `security` attribute set to true in security.yaml, no problem, my authenticator class automatically launches and runs well. I can authenticated myself and then get a filled user instance in Symfony.

But now, what I'd like to do is a simple login page that would play the authentication process and then redirect the user to a page defined by the application admin in config files (for eventually add an authenticate button in app with public access).

My question is: how can I launch this authentication process from a controller as my login route has a public access (and then authentication system is never launched) ?

Something like that :

```
class AuthenticationController extends AbstractController
{
    public function login(Request $request, Security $security)
    {
        if (!$this->getUser())
            $security->pleaseLaunchTheAuthenticationProcess()
        
        return new RedirectResponse('/my_path');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the UserAuthenticatorInterface:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/some-route", name="some_route")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserAuthenticatorInterface $userAuthenticator
     * @param AuthenticatorInterface $authenticator
     * @return Response
     */
    public function book(
        Request                     $request,
        UserAuthenticatorInterface  $userAuthenticator,
        AuthenticatorInterface      $authenticator
    ): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser() instanceof User) {
            $userAuthenticator->authenticateUser($this->getUser(), $authenticator, $request);
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('/my_path');
    }
```

You will have an error about AuthenticatorInterface which cannot be launched. You have to declare it manually in your service.yaml:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
            $authenticator: '@security.authenticator.form_login.main'
```

Comment: I had to modify the last part to point to my custom authenticator, but I still have an error cause authenticateUser needs a User instance as parameter and null is given.
The problem is I'm in a reusable Bundle and I can't instanciate a User class because I don't know which class the developer will use :(

Comment: You must pass a User, so change the if as I did in my comment. If user is null, then you will have to create one manually, persist and save it, then log it in

Comment: Ah ok my bad, I didn't notice you changed the if condition. But the thing is it would be in a reusable bundle, so I can't really instanciate a User because I want to let the developper choose to use its own User class

Comment: Then in the if, just check it is instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface.